# Chrome and Firefox ignore Javascript style top and left

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

I'm playing a little with styles from Javascript and I'm trying to place some div where I want. This code works perfectly in Safari (where every div is placed where left and top says) but it does not work on Chrome and Firefox. That are not the

```
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = this.numberOfSystem + 'circle' + i;


    div.x = ((this.centerX) + ((this.lenghtMain/2 + this.lenghtSmall/2 + 50) * Math.sin( 2 * Math.PI / this.amount * i))) - (this.lenghtSmall / 2);  
    div.y = ((this.centerY) + ((this.lenghtMain/2 + this.lenghtSmall/2 + 50) * Math.cos( 2 * Math.PI / this.amount * i))) - (this.lenghtSmall / 2);

    div.style.position = "fixed";
    div.style.left = div.x + "px";
    div.style.top = div.y + "px";
    div.style.width = this.lenghtSmall;
    div.style.height = this.lenghtSmall;
```

The problem with Chrome and Firefox is when I check in developer tools style.top and style.left are not defined so all the elements appears positioned at the top left corner. From developer tools -> elements i get this

```
<div id="0circle1" style="position: fixed; width: 250px; height: 250px; text-align: center; background-image: url(file:///Users/Imanol/Documents/Webs/Portfolio2/circulo200.png); background-size: 100%;"><div style="margin: 20%;">Curriculum</div></div>
```

Nothing about top and left... In Safari it works perfectly and the elements are placed in the places they are meant to be. This is what a I get from Safari.

```
<div id="0circle0" style="position: fixed; left: 340.0003905596077px; top: 360.04122042944215px; width: 250px; height: 250px; background-image: url(file:///Users/Imanol/Documents/Webs/Portfolio2/circulo200.png); background-size: 100%; text-align: center;"><div style="margin: 20%;">Studies<br><br><img width="100" height="100" src="pastel.jpg"></div></div>
```

I tried with Math.round() but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in that code, what are the values of div.x and div.y? Both chrome and firefox have developer modes so you can easily set breakpoints in the code

Comment: What does `this` refer to? could you show us the entire relevant code?

Comment: ok! breakpoint helped me to find the error... i did not think that it could be a mistake in calculations of div.x and div.x so i never checked their values... the problem came from this.centerX and this.centerY that were calculated using document.width and document.height and these worked in safari but not in firefox or chrome, so in these two the returned NaN... i changed them for window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight and work perfect everywhere... thank you!

Comment: So answer your own question...

Comment: Yes, you can answer your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem came from this.centerX and this.centerY that were calculated using document.width and document.height and these worked in safari but not in firefox or chrome, so in these two they returned NaN... i changed them for window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight and work perfect everywhere... thank you!